# Purchasing a domain in SiteGround gives an error

Tags: dns, hosting

I live in the Philippines and I find SiteGround good. As a result, I tried purchasing a plan but there was an error saying that "SiteGround services are not available in the selected country.” under Client Information after selecting Philippines as country.

My question is if I change the Client Information to USA somehow, will there be a problem if I use SiteGround in Philippines? Will there be future problems?

Comment: Hi, I'm also stuck here, Did you find any answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like SiteGround is not allowing people from certain countries to use their services. From what I know this is because they want to focus on key markets and it seems like one of the other reasons is to not allow people from certain countries to use their services because of regulatory issues.

Take a look at what they say:

> I see your query, you're correct, unfortunately, we had to stop servicing several countries and regions due to specific local requirements that we must comply with
> Heavier regulations and growing tax complexities may have been a burden on SG.

> Another negative trend that we have been monitoring in your region and several others is the heavier regulations and growing tax complexities